# Can PowerBI direct query work with SQL row-level security?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, row-level-security

I am trying to implement Direct query report on SQL database with row-level security. PowerBI is not letting me fire a Stored Procedure(`sp_set_session_context`) in direct query mode.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your current SQL for the report?

Comment: Are you trying to say, that there is some custom made RLS-like functionality implemented in your database? Because SQL Server's RLS doesn't care about the session context.

Comment: @Charlieface ....We are using SQL server.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov... Our application is a multi-tenant solution. We have row-level security (filters) implemented at tenant id in our SQL server DB. When ever we need to fetch data of the tenant, we need to run the context SP and then run the select query.

` EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'TenantId', @value = 'xyz' 
`

When select is fired without executing sp_set_session_context we get 0 rows.

Comment: So what's your current code for the Direct Query, how are you trying to call the sproc and why is i t not working? Please be clear

Comment: Basically when we use direct query in power bi and provide ` EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'TenantId', @value = 'xyz' ` in the **SQL statement(optional, requires database)** field , power bi is trying to wrap the content in a select statement like 

`select * from 
(EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'TenantId,@value='10')`  before it starts execution.